# [ROS2 LAUNCH] How to correctly create a Lifecycle launch file

Tags: ros2, roslaunch, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to write a Python launch file that handles the state transitions of my lifecycle node. In particular I would like to launch a "Robot State Publisher" node when my node reaches the `inactive` state after that it as been configured.

I followed as example the launch file on Github as indicated [here](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Launch-system):

https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/master/launch_ros/examples/lifecycle_pub_sub_launch.py

but I get the following error when I launch it:

> [ERROR] [launch.LaunchService]: Caught
> exception in launch (see debug for
> traceback): launch file at
> '/home/walter/devel/ros2_ws/install/stereolabs_zed/share/stereolabs_zed/launch/zed.py'
> does not contain the required function
> 'generate_launch_description()'

Is the example updated to the new launch style available in Bouncy?

This is my launch:

```
"""Launch a lifecycle ZED node and the Robot State Publisher"""

import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))  # noqa
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', 'launch'))  # noqa

import launch
import launch.actions
import launch.events

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch_ros import get_default_launch_description
import launch_ros.actions
import launch_ros.events
import launch_ros.events.lifecycle

import lifecycle_msgs.msg


def main(argv=sys.argv[1:]):
    """Main."""    

    # use: 'zed' for "ZED" camera - 'zedm' for "ZED mini" camera
    camera_model = 'zedm' 

    # URDF file to be loaded by Robot State Publisher
    urdf = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('stereolabs_zed'),
                        'urdf', camera_model + '.urdf')
    
    # ZED Configurations to be loaded by ZED Node
    config_common = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('stereolabs_zed'),
                        'config', 'common.yaml')

    config_camera = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('stereolabs_zed'),
                        'config', camera_model + '.yaml')

    # Set LOG format
    os.environ['RCUTILS_CONSOLE_OUTPUT_FORMAT'] = '{time}: [{name}] [{severity}]\t{message}'

    # Prepare the ZED node
    zed_node = launch_ros.actions.LifecycleNode( package='stereolabs_zed', 
                                                 node_executable='zed_wrapper_node',
                                                 output='screen', 
                                                 arguments=['__params:='+config_common, # Common parameters
                                                            '__params:='+config_camera  # Camera related parameters
                                                           ]
                                               )
    # Launch Description
    ld = launch.LaunchDescription()

    # Make the ZED node take the 'configure' transition.
    emit_event_to_request_that_zed_does_configure_transition = launch.actions.EmitEvent(
        event=launch_ros.events.lifecycle.ChangeState(
            lifecycle_node_matcher=launch.events.process.matches_action(zed_node),
            transition_id=lifecycle_msgs.msg.Transition.TRANSITION_CONFIGURE,
        )
    )

    # When the ZED node reaches the 'inactive' state, start the Robot State Publisher and make it take the 'activate' transition.
    register_event_handler_for_zed_reaches_inactive_state = launch.actions.RegisterEventHandler(
        launch_ros.event_handlers.OnStateTransition(
            target_lifecycle_node=zed_node, goal_state='inactive',
            entities=[
                       # Log
                       launch.actions.LogInfo(msg="'ZED' reached the 'inactive' state, start the 'Robot State Publisher' node and 'activating'."),
                       # Robot State Publisher
                       launch_ros.actions.Node( package='robot_state_publisher', 
                                                node_executable='robot_state_publisher',
                                                output='screen', 
                                                arguments=[urdf]
                                              ),
                       # Change State event
                       launch.actions.EmitEvent( event=launch_ros.events.lifecycle.ChangeState(
                         lifecycle_node_matcher=launch.events.process.matches_action(zed_node),
                         transition_id=lifecycle_msgs.msg.Transition.TRANSITION_ACTIVATE,
                        )),
             ],
        )
    )

    # When the ZED node reaches the 'active' state, log a message.
    register_event_handler_for_talker_reaches_active_state = launch.actions.RegisterEventHandler(
        launch_ros.event_handlers.OnStateTransition(
            target_lifecycle_node=talker_node, goal_state='active',
            entities=[ launch.actions.LogInfo( msg="'ZED' reached the 'active' state" ),],
        )
    )    

    # Add the actions to the launch description.
    # The order they are added reflects the order in which they will be executed.
    ld.add_action(register_event_handler_for_zed_reaches_inactive_state)
    ld.add_action(register_event_handler_for_zed_reaches_active_state)
    ld.add_action(zed_node)
    ld.add_action(emit_event_to_request_that_zed_does_configure_transition)

    print('Starting introspection of launch description...')
    print('')

    print(launch.LaunchIntrospector().format_launch_description(ld))

    print('')
    print('Starting launch of launch description...')
    print('')

    # ls = launch.LaunchService(argv=argv, debug=True)
    ls = launch.LaunchService(argv=argv)
    ls.include_launch_description(get_default_launch_description(prefix_output_with_name=False))
    ls.include_launch_description(ld)
    return ls.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My ROS2 configuration:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- ROS2 Bouncy from source
- Updated  to latest `master`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304370/%5Bros2-launch%5D-how-to-correctly-create-a-lifecycle-launch-file/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2018-09-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-11-08**:
`Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback):` -> Add `-d` to ros2 launch before package and launch file name to get the traceback:

```
ros2 launch -d foo bar_launch.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to start the launch file with the `ros2 launch` command, you should define a `generate_launch_description` function that returns the `LaunchDescription`instead of a `main`.

E.g

```
def generate_launch_description():

    # ...

    # Launch Description
    ld = launch.LaunchDescription()

    # ...
  
    # Add the actions to the launch description.
    # The order they are added reflects the order in which they will be executed.
    ld.add_action(register_event_handler_for_zed_reaches_inactive_state)
    ld.add_action(register_event_handler_for_zed_reaches_active_state)
    ld.add_action(zed_node)
    ld.add_action(emit_event_to_request_that_zed_does_configure_transition)

    return ld
```

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2018-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2018-09-27**:
Thank you. I missed the information about how to migrate from legacy launch to the new system available in Bouncy. Very useful

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the final version of the converted launch file. Thank you @jacobperron :

```
"""Launch a lifecycle ZED node and the Robot State Publisher"""

import os


import launch
from launch import LaunchIntrospector

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import EmitEvent
from launch.actions import LogInfo
from launch.actions import RegisterEventHandler
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.actions import LifecycleNode
from launch_ros.events.lifecycle import ChangeState
from launch_ros.event_handlers import OnStateTransition

import lifecycle_msgs.msg

def generate_launch_description():

    # use: 'zed' for "ZED" camera - 'zedm' for "ZED mini" camera
    camera_model = 'zedm' 

    # URDF file to be loaded by Robot State Publisher
    urdf = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('stereolabs_zed'), 'urdf', camera_model + '.urdf')
    
    # ZED Configurations to be loaded by ZED Node
    config_common = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('stereolabs_zed'), 'config', 'common.yaml')

    config_camera = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('stereolabs_zed'), 'config', camera_model + '.yaml')

    # Set LOG format
    os.environ['RCUTILS_CONSOLE_OUTPUT_FORMAT'] = '{time}: [{name}] [{severity}]\t{message}'

    # Launch Description
    ld = launch.LaunchDescription()

    # Prepare the ZED node
    zed_node = LifecycleNode(
        node_namespace = 'zed',        # must match the namespace in config -> YAML
        node_name = 'zed_node',        # must match the node name in config -> YAML
        package = 'stereolabs_zed',
        node_executable = 'zed_wrapper_node',
        output = 'screen',
        parameters = [
            config_common,  # Common parameters
            config_camera,  # Camera related parameters
        ]
    )

    # Prepare the Robot State Publisher node
    rsp_node = Node(
        node_name = 'zed_state_publisher',
        package = 'robot_state_publisher',
        node_executable = 'robot_state_publisher',
        output = 'screen',
        arguments = [urdf, 'robot_description:=zed_description']
    )

    # Make the ZED node take the 'configure' transition
    zed_configure_trans_event = EmitEvent(
        event=ChangeState(
            lifecycle_node_matcher = launch.events.process.matches_action(zed_node),
            transition_id = lifecycle_msgs.msg.Transition.TRANSITION_CONFIGURE,
        )
    )

    # Make the ZED node take the 'activate' transition
    zed_activate_trans_event = EmitEvent(
        event = ChangeState(
            lifecycle_node_matcher = launch.events.process.matches_action(zed_node),
            transition_id = lifecycle_msgs.msg.Transition.TRANSITION_ACTIVATE,
         )
    )

    # When the ZED node reaches the 'inactive' state, make it take the 'activate' transition and start the Robot State Publisher
    zed_inactive_state_handler = RegisterEventHandler(
        OnStateTransition(
            target_lifecycle_node = zed_node,
            goal_state = 'inactive',
            entities = [
                # Log
                LogInfo( msg = "'ZED' reached the 'INACTIVE' state, start the 'Robot State Publisher' node and 'activating'." ),
                # Robot State Publisher
                rsp_node,
                # Change State event ( inactive -> active )
                zed_activate_trans_event,
            ],
        )
    )

    # When the ZED node reaches the 'active' state, log a message.
    zed_active_state_handler = RegisterEventHandler(
        OnStateTransition(
            target_lifecycle_node = zed_node,
            goal_state = 'active',
            entities = [
                # Log
                LogInfo( msg = "'ZED' reached the 'ACTIVE' state" ),
            ],
        )
    )

    # Add the actions to the launch description.
    # The order they are added reflects the order in which they will be executed.
    ld.add_action( zed_inactive_state_handler )
    ld.add_action( zed_active_state_handler )
    ld.add_action( zed_node )
    ld.add_action( zed_configure_trans_event)

    return ld
```

---

Originally posted by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) with karma: 541 on 2018-09-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lingjie](https://answers.ros.org/users/69137/lingjie/) on 2021-02-01**:
Similar to how we start the rsp node when ed node reach inactive state.

Is there a way to stop a running ROS node when the lifecycle node reach a specific state?

Thank you.

**Comment by [flynneva](https://answers.ros.org/users/44351/flynneva/) on 2021-05-25**:
thank you for posting this!!!! spent a long time searching for the solution..this was it!